# Changing the role from Technical lead to Project manager

Tags: project-management, promotion

I'm currently in the role of Tech lead for a small company. I lead a team of 3 to 4 people. Most of my responsibilities include, task assignment, tracking and reporting, technical discussions etc. Now that I have reached age of forty and  would like to see myself in a management position rather being a developer/tech lead position. I would like to get involved in tasks like staff management, tracking  project status, performance reviews, Budgeting, Resource allocations etc. In other words, I want a career growth which shifts me to a management role. I believe I'm suitable for the position as I am a reasonably good communicator, leader and have good time management skills in addition to this I know the intricacies of the project,staff and work place. I understand that certifications and degrees would definitely help, but how would I honestly self evaluate my qualifications and attributes to be a manager against the current bench mark for an IT Project manager.

Answer (score 4):

Ask for training.

Project Management (at least here in the UK) has a recognized [certification](https://www.prince2.com/), so gaining that would be a good step toward making the step towards a project management role.

This won't be as simple as just changing your job role.  You need to actively learn this stuff.

Answer (score 1):

> How would I get started and convince my manager ?

Ask for it!
Seriously, if that is the road you want to take, you have to talk to your manager about it, explaining why you wanna take that role and why you could be good at it.
Bear in mind that if you are in a small company is possible that sort of change cannot be made in te short term, so start considering looking for another job if you really want to go for it.
And as snow said, is important that you gain PM specific knowledge, so you should educate yourself (so you can show your manager you are capable of doing it) as well as asking formal training.

Comment: Thanks @Homerothompson. I would talk to the manager, but I see that formal training is just a namesake. There are great managers with out any training. I would like to be one of them.

Comment: The advantage of formal training is that is given by people who studied the best ways of doing those sort of things. Of course you can be a great manager without it, but with it you could be even better

Comment: More and more companies are requiring the PMC certification to promote people to project manager in my neck of the woods including the company I work for.  From people I know who have taken the test, the material is very complex especially if you have no business background.

Comment: Thanks ! My managers agreed and accepted to mentor me as a manager after I have asked. Your advise really helped ! I will gain PM knowledge using PMI.

Answer (score 1):

The best thing to do is to sit down with your manager and talk about your future career growth. One of the roles of manager is to help your employees reach their next step in career growth. Ask him/her straight up what you need to do to get into a management position vs a tech lead.

Mentoring is a HUGE part of what managers are supposed to do. However if you never tell your manager where you want to go they'll never be able to mentor you in that direction.

You're not going to just jump into a management position without any new training/schooling though. You need to learn to be a manager before they'll let you be a manager. Similar to how you need to learn to be a developer before someone will let you be a developer. Training may include getting Project Management Certifications. Or going back to school for a MBA. But thinking you'll get by without any of that is kind of silly when most other applicants for management positions will have one of those. It's also a way to get a higher salary.

Comment: Thanks ! My managers agreed and accepted to mentor me as a manager after I have asked. Your advise really helped !